# Does Linq in Entity Framework code first use SQL or does it get the whole table first?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, ef-code-first

I've been looking at some tutorials that are using Entity Framework code first for database definition and access. I was wondering when using Linq to query, is the linq transformed to SQL `(select * from mytable where id = :id)` or is the entire table retrieved from the database  and then the rows are filtered out?

Does

```
var item = DbContext.Users.Where(i => i.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();
```

run the SQL

```
select * 
from Users 
where id = :Id
```

or does it get all the data from the users table in the database and then after that use linq to filter out the correct row?

given the class

```
 public class ApplicationUser 
    { 
        #region Constructor 
        public ApplicationUser() 
        { 

        } 
        #endregion Constructor 

        #region Properties 
        [Key] 
        [Required] 
        public string Id { get; set; } 
        [Required] 
        [MaxLength(128)] 
        public string UserName { get; set; } 
        [Required] 
        public string Email { get; set; } 
        #endregion Properties 
    }
```

and the dbcontext

```
 public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext 
    { 
        #region Constructor 
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options) 
        { 
        } 
        #endregion Constructor 

        #region Methods 
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) 
        { 
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder); 

modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().ToTable("Users"); 
                        #endregion Methods 

        #region Properties 
        public DbSet<ApplicationUser> Users { get; set; } 
        #endregion Properties 
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var item = DbContext.Users.Where(i => i.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();
```

will perform

```
select top(1) 
<list of column names> 
from mytable 
where id = :id

var item = DbContext.Users.ToList().Where(i => i.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();
```

will grab everything from the SQL table and perform the search in memory.

Comment: I would say the first part of this answer isn't true. The query will include TOP 1 in the SELECT, because of the FirstOrDefault() in LINQ. I think @Habib's answer is correct.

Comment: you are right.  I'll update the answer. it also won't do a *. it will list out the columns.

Answer (score 4):

It will not get the whole table since you used `FirstOrDefault()` in your query.

The query would be something like

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM ...
```

It is always a better idea to use a profiler (SQL profiler in SQL Server case), and see the actual query getting executed on the store.

If you iterate the query and then use `FirstOrDefault` this will bring the all the records matching the condition in memory from DB. So if you have a query like *(don't do that)*:

```
var item = DbContext.Users.Where(i => i.Id == id).ToList().FirstOrDefault();
```

and if your query didn't has any condition then it will bring the whole table in memory.

```
var item = DbContext.Users.ToList().FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: var item = DbContext.Users.Where(i => i.Id == id).ToList().FirstOrDefault(); will not bring the whole table.  it will only bring back the results of the where clause.